# AngularJS looping through an array in JSON and listing in a table - values not showing

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

What I am trying to do is run a search against an API (which I have working) and then display the returned information in a table. Below is my code and a mocked up image of what I am trying to achieve plus what I currently see.

**JSON**

```
{
    "legalDescription": "Pork & Egg Gala Pie",
    "QUID": [
        "Pork 38%"
    ],
    "warningStatement": [
        "Caution: May contain bone"
    ],
    "GTIN": "0213090000000",
    "allergenInfo": [
        {
            "allergenName": "Contains",
            "allergenValues": "Wheat"
        },
        {
            "allergenName": "Contains",
            "allergenValues": "Egg"
        }
    ],
    "href": "http://product.global.tesco.org:8080/v2/products/counterproducts/0213090000000"
}
```

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.products = [];

    $scope.runCountersSearch = function() {

        $http.get("http://product.global.tesco.org:8080/v2/products/counterproducts/" + $scope.searchInputCounters).success(function(theData) {

            $scope.products.push(theData);
        });

    }
```

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat = "oneProduct in products">
                    <td> {{oneProduct.legalDescription}} </td>
                    <td ng-repeat="quid in oneProduct.QUID"> {{quid.QUID}} </td>
                    <td ng-repeat="warning in oneProduct.warningStatement">{{warning.warningStatement}} </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

**What I see**
[image: What I See]
**What I want to get**
[image: What I want to get]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `"QUID"` and `"warningStatement"` you have an array of strings so you can change your HTML like that:

```
<tr ng-repeat = "oneProduct in products">
    <td> {{oneProduct.legalDescription}} </td>
    <td ng-repeat="quid in oneProduct.QUID"> {{quid[$index]}} </td>
    <td ng-repeat="warning in oneProduct.warningStatement">{{warning[$index]}} </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
var url = 'http://product.global.tesco.org:8080/v2/products/counterproducts/';

$http.get(url + $scope.searchInputCounters).success(function(theData) {
    $scope.products.push(theData.data);
});
```

If you look at the [angular $http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http/#general-usage)

> The response object has these properties:
>
> - **data** – `{string|Object}` – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
> - **status** – `{number}` – HTTP status code of the response.
> - **headers** – `{function([headerName])}` – Header getter function.
> - **config** – `{Object}` – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
> - **statusText** – `{string}` – HTTP status text of the response.

So when the data comes back you in a response, you need to extract it using the `data` property

**Also keep in mind that `QUID` and `warningStatement` are arrays, not strings.**